# dynamic loading of a component in vue

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

i have a tree of objects that im showing using vue. Each node in the tree can be of a specific type, and users can click through the tree from node to node. Most nodes can be rendered the same, using a default template. But some nodes require drastically different rendering. So I figure id use specific components for each node type.

I know I can use the "component is=" method, but how can I load specific components based on a node's type, or if there isnt a specific component for that type, load a default component. Is there some way to check if a component exists? Or should I maintain some array with all types that need a specific component?

Comment: "should I maintain some array with all types that need a specific component" -> yes

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, you could use `<component :is>`. Here's a possible implementation:

You can call a function `getNodeComponentByType(node)` which returns a specific type of component based on the current node.

E.g.In your template (i.e. if this is how you render tree nodes)
`<component v-for="node in nodes" :is="getNodeComponentByType(node)">`

and subsequently implement this method as shown:

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app,
  data: {
    ...
  },
  
  methods: {
    getNodeComponentByType: function (node) {
        switch(node.type) {
            case 'typeA' : return ATypeTreeNodeComponent;
            case 'typeB': return BTypeTreeNodeComponent;
            default: return defaultTreeNodeComponent;

        }
    }
  },
  components: {
      ATypeTreeNodeComponent,
      BTypeTreeNodeComponent,
      defaultTreeNodeComponent
      ...
  }
})
```

Hope this helps.